# Greedy highlighting in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

For now I have this text in DB.

> This is a good example of text. Good bye

Mapping (Ruby).

```
 mapping do
   indexes :content, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
 end
```

Search query:

```
{
  query: {
    match: {
      content: {
        query: search_input,
        analyzer: :english,
        type: :phrase
      }
    }
  },
  highlight: {
    tags_schema: :styled,
    fields: {
      content: {}
    }
  }
}
```

When I search word "good", then I have the following result:

```
This is a <em class=\"hlt1\">good example of text. Good</em> bye.
```

instead of highlighting every word "good" separately

Comment: Try to enable term vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Now all works. I just restarted elasticsearch